# which of the following function are reimann integrable on the interval $[0,1].$?

Tags: real-analysis

which of the  following  function are reimann integrable on the interval $[0,1].$?

$1)$ $f(x) =\begin{cases}   1,  &\text{if x is  rational }\\
0, &\text{if  x is irrational }         \end{cases}$

$2)$ $f(x) =\begin{cases}   1,  &\text{if x } \in \{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,.......,\alpha_n\}\\
0, &\text{otherwise }         \end{cases}$

i know  that  option $1) $ will not reimann integrable  because  it is not bounded.

im confused  about option $2)$

Any hints/solution

Comment: Strange..!! (1) is not bounded?

Comment: (2) There are finite number of discontinuities. So Riemann integrable

Comment: your question is already has an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2274177/riemann-integrabilty-of-an-indicator-function)

Comment: Thanks U @ChinnapparajR

Comment: [Reimann](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=reimann)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, for (1), f is bounded, since $|f| \leq 1$, so your reasoning is incorrect.

Hint: Take an arbitrary partition of [0,1] and show that $U(f,P) - L(f,P)$ can not be made smaller than $1$.

Alternatively, you can notice that the set of discontinuities does not have measure 0 ($f$ is discontinuous everywhere)

For (2), the function has finitely many discontinuities, so is integrable.