# why $U(P,f) - L(P,f) < \epsilon ?$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Consider the following function on $[0,1]$:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&x\in\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}\\0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
The $a_i$ are fixed and all in $[0,1]$. Determine whether $f$ is Rieman integrable or not.

**My attempt** :  I found the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2274177/557708)

Here is the outline of the given answer

> Take a partition $P$ of $[0,1]$ that is defined as:
> $$
> P = \left\{0,a_1-\frac{\epsilon}{2},a_1+\frac{\epsilon}{2},\dots,a_n-\frac{\epsilon}{2},a_n+\frac{\epsilon}{2},1\right\}.
> $$
> Clearly, $U(P,f) = \epsilon N$ and $L(P,f) = 0$. Since for any given $\epsilon>0$, a partition that could yield
> $$
> U(P,f) - L(P,f) < \epsilon
> $$
> can be found, $f$ is Riemann integrable.

**My confusion** :Here $$U(P,f)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}M_i(x_i- x_{i-1})=  n\epsilon$$ and

$$L(P,f)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_i(x_i- x_{i-1})=  0$$

$$\implies U(P,f) - L(P,f)  > \epsilon   \implies  n\epsilon -0 > \epsilon $$

My confusion is that  why  $U(P,f) - L(P,f) < \epsilon ?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right to be confused here. That answer is misleading (at best).

Given $\varepsilon>0$, that answer shows that there is a partition $P$ such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P)=n\varepsilon$ (not $N\varepsilon$; there is no $N$ here). So, given $\varepsilon>0$, take $\varepsilon'<\frac\varepsilon n$ and consider the partition$$P=\left\{0,a_1-\frac{\varepsilon'}2,a_1+\frac{\varepsilon'}2,\ldots,a_n-\frac{\varepsilon'}2,a_n+\frac{\varepsilon'}2,1\right\}.$$Then$$U(f,P)-L(f,P)=n\varepsilon'<\varepsilon.$$